# linux: Print String at The End of Each Output Line

Tags: linux, solaris

I execute below script

```
grep -i 'Exception' Exceptions.log | 
sort | 
uniq -c | 
sort -n
```

and get below result (each time result set will be different)

```
6 java.lang.NullPointerException
48 java.sql.SQLException
64 excep.NotFoundException
671 exception.ParseErrorException
690 Exception
```

Actually I want to print the filename as well at the start or end of each line

```
6 java.lang.NullPointerException Exceptions
48 java.sql.SQLException Exceptions
64 excep.NotFoundException Exceptions
671 exception.ParseErrorException Exceptions
690 Exception Exceptions
```

OR

```
Exceptions 6 java.lang.NullPointerException
Exceptions 48 java.sql.SQLException
Exceptions 64 excep.NotFoundException
Exceptions 671 exception.ParseErrorException
Exceptions 690 Exception
```

Please help me to achieve this object.

Comment: Why are you not adding the string `Exceptions.log`, as that seems to be the name of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Yon can use `-H` option e.g. `grep -H <SEARCH>`

```
   -H, --with-filename
          Print the file name for each match.  This is  the  default  when
          there is more than one file to search.
```

Check [man](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html) page for more options

Answer (score 0):

It seems easiest to tack on a `...| sed -e 's/^/Exceptions.log /'` to the pipeline.   But you might just do:

```
awk '/Exception/ {a[$0 " " FILENAME]++} 
    END {for(i in a) print a[i], i}' Exceptions.log | sort -n
```

Which would allow you to easily search multiple files.  (Eg, just replace Exceptions.log with `*`)